# CS-CART Paypal Adaptive Payments Integration Issue

Tags: paypal, cs-cart

We have a marketplace website based on CS-CART, which has a module to integrate the marketplace with Paypal for adaptive payments (module developed by Simtech). For the primary merchant account, I set up an adaptive payments account with Paypal, linked a bank account and credit card and apparently this should be all good to go.

I plugged my Paypal credentials into the CS-CART module and then tried to verify a vendor paypal account. However, I get the error:

> "Cannot determine Paypal Account Status"

The vendor account is also verified as far as I know - with a linked bank account and credit card. I don't even know if this error relates to my merchant account or the vendor account.

CS-CART always tell me to approach Paypal for a solution, so not much help there. I have called Paypal support multiple times but they never give me a straight answer. On this occasion, they redirected me to various support forums, including StackOverflow.

Any help in the right direction would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in Administrator panle  run CRON job . CRON job url link is located in PP Adaptive Paymant add-on in CS CART. Just click on this link. payment of Vendir will be verified

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Paypal Adaptive Payments is not longer supported by Paypal.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/

Alternatively, you will have to apply for Paypal Marketplaces below:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/prerequisites/#

Once you will be approved to use Paypal Marketplaces, you will be able to use it for payment handling and processing on your CS-Cart website.